# Redirecionamento para View em outra estrutura

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto, que está em uma área, nele, meu controller Principal, tem uma action que, quando chamada, deverá retornar uma view que está em outra pasta, porém, dentro da mesma área.

```
return View("OutraPasta/Index.cshtml");

return View("~/Views/OutraPasta/Index.cshtml");

return View("~/Views/Area/OutraPasta/Index.cshtml");
```

mas nenhuma das opções retorna, de fato, essa view.

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Redirecionar pra outra view, ué...

Comment: Mas por que outro diretório dentro da mesma área? Por que o template da View não pode ficar no mesmo diretório?

Comment: Porque é necessário que cada módulo esteja em uma estrutura própria. Mas a view que requisita está na estrutura principal. E o responsável quer ver nas views as pastas dos módulos. Isso vem ao caso? =T

Comment: Sim, a área tem este objetivo: oferecer uma estrutura própria, como um módulo, destacada da estrutura principal. Possivelmente você está incorrendo em uma má prática.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem mistério, é só usar o caminho completo da view.

```
return View("~/Areas/NomeDaArea/Views/NomeDaView.cshtml")
```

Comment: Não brilhou. Será algum problema de rota?

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com rotas. Tem certeza que a chamada cai corretamente no controller?

Comment: Sim. Tem um bp lá.

Comment: E essa view tá em alguma area mesmo ou ela tá na raiz da aplicação?

Comment: Funcionou perfeito. Deixei faltar o: Views/ no meio do caminho. Obrigada, jbueno. (=